# firebase login otp verification

Tags: java, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

My app is not sending code(otp) for login with phone(firebase) and is printing the following error in Logcat. But it is logging in with testing purpose number manually inserted in firebase console.

ERROR
[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17010 null.

what could be the problem and how can l solve it? Please Help.

Login with phone number to a firebase console with android studio application. l was expecting firebase to send me the otp code for verification

Answer (score 0):

Have you added phone as sign in method on the firebase auth console? Navigate in the firebase dashboard to Authentication, sign in method, and enable phone.

Comment: Yes l have, but l am trying to use both email and phone number, could that be a problem?

Comment: Do you have them both enabled?

Comment: Yes, they are both enabled.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try to add SHA1 and SHA-256 keys to your Android Studio project.**

(This case may be caused by the security rules of Firebase Authentication.)

Comment: l have added the SHA1 and SHA-256 fingerprints. But still the onComplete method that should send OTP doesnt execute.